# How to fetch all the urls which are not linked using regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to fetch all the urls from the given string which are not linked(url without anchor tag).

I know the regex `(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?` to fetch all the urls from the given string.

**Input:**

```
<div class='test'>
<p>Heading</p>
<a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a>
www.yahoo.com
http://www.rediff.com
<a href='http://www.overflow.com'>www.overflow.com</a> 
</div>
```

**output:**

1. www.yahoo.com
2. http://www.rediff.com

Kindly advise.

Comment: 1) Parse the HTML with a DOM parser, 2) Remove all anchor tags, 3) Collect the URLs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  i think regex is faster than DOM parser because my input always a string content not a HTML content.

Comment: You can [try like this](https://regex101.com/r/wL1pI0/2) by skipping: `(?is)<a.*?<\/a>(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+\.\S+` (is just an example, use your own pattern after pipe `|`)

Comment: @raj Try this `(?<!href=\')(\s+|http:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|https:\/\/)\w+\.[\w\-]+\.\w+` [Demon here](https://regex101.com/r/kA8eQ8/1)

Comment: Faster does not mean safer. Yes, `(*SKIP)(*F)` should work.

Comment: @bobblebubble, thanks. its working fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, why?

Comment: There is no wrong in my question. i have searched answer for this question through net and i cant found any answers that is the reason i raised question. But someone downvoted for my question.

Comment: They posted wrong answers, so losing their reputation.

Comment: And why doesn't bobblebubble post the answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because it's not an answer, just an example.

Answer (score -1):

Use library for get dom tree html, and get all links.
for example you can use simplehtml   http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
       echo $element->href . '<br>'; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple use this will get href source:

```
href='(.+?)'
```

Comment: this bad way. parsing html by regexp